# How to get value of all items in a loop?JavaScript Sharepoin2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have created an html table and for each row there is a checkbox row. I am getting the `ID` of rows that are checked and I am trying to create a cookie with the `ID` of rows that are checked and I am trying to name the cookie `EmployeeID` + `i` and the value is `closestTr`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    createCookie("EmployeeID" + i, closestTr);
  }
```

Cookies are working perfect. and here is the full code:

```
$('#myHTMLTable1').find('tr').each(function () {

      var row = $(this);
      count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                closestTr = row.closest('tr').attr('id');                             
            }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    createCookie("EmployeeID" + i, closestTr);
    }
```

but in another page I have to get those cookies that I have created and I am trying to get like this:

```
var empID;

var i = 0;
while (i < cacID1) { //cacID1 is the number of checked items

 empID = getCookie("EmployeeID" + i);

 alert(empID);

i++;
}
```

if I check the first row in my table I can get its ID which is `1`

BUT if I check the first and the second I am getting twice the ID of second row;

and if i check 8 rows all i am getting is the id of last row 8 times

please help me!

Comment: Looks like `closestTr`'s value is being set every time it finds a checked check box. Try combining the `$.each` and the `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    createCookie("EmployeeID" + i, closestTr);
 }
```

Inside of your each function, for example:

```
$('#myHTMLTable1').find('tr').each(function () {

      var row = $(this);
      count = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;

      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                closestTr = row.closest('tr').attr('id');                             
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               createCookie("EmployeeID" + i, closestTr);
     }
    });
```

Then you can take each value of `closestTr`.

Comment: the problem is not with creating cookies, they are being created perfect but the problem stands when trying to get cookie